# Apply Plus as a new head to a list but prevent evaluation

Tags: evaluation, hold

I would like to illustrate to users the use of `Apply` with an example.

```
Plus@@Range[5]
(*15*)
```

To display what is happening I'm interesting in showing the expression after the `List` head has been replaced by `Plus`, but before evaluation. I can do it abstractly with an arbitrary symbol:

```
f@@Range[5]
(*f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*)
```

How do I control the evaluation flow to do the same with `f` replaced by `Plus`?

Edit:

To be more precise, I was wondering if I could control the evaluation so that the output would be shown as:

```
 Plus[1,2,3,4,5]
```

With `Range[5]` being evaluated, but not `Plus`.

Comment: If you want to see the process, you can also do `Trace@Apply[Plus, lis] // Column` which gives screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iOgr.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
expr = Range[5];
expr1 = Plus @@ expr;
expr2 = Defer@Plus @@ expr;
TreeForm /@ {expr, expr1, expr2}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
expr1 = Inactive[Plus] @@ Range[5]
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

If you need to further calculate it to the end make this:

```
expr2 = expr1 // Activate

(*  15  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is close but not exactly what I had in mind. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
 HoldForm[Plus] @@ Range[5]
 (* Plus[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] *)
```

Comment: Use `HoldForm` or `Defer` (as in Syed's answer), depending on how the output is to be used.  See the Properties and Relations section of the documentation for `Defer`.